# How to display only checked apps in the custom launcher

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview, android-launcher

I want to get the specific apps from all Installed apps and display it in the drawer layout of my custom launcher. I don't know how to pass the details checked apps from one activity to another activity (i.e.) from SelectAppActivity to MainActivity.

Instead of Toast in `SelectAppActivity` I need to get the checked apps (Package name, Icon, label) and pass it to MainActivity .

**SelectAppActivity.java**

```
public class SelectAppActivity extends Activity {
     AppInfoAdapter adapter ;
     AppInfo app_info[] ;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.appselecter_activity_main);


            final ListView listApplication = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listApplication);
            Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getApplicationInfo();
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final List<PackageInfo> pInfo = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
            final MyAppAdapter myadapter;


            pInfo.addAll(pm.getInstalledPackages(0));
            app_info = new AppInfo[pInfo.size()];

            int counter = 0;
            for(PackageInfo item: pInfo){
                try{

                    applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(item.packageName, 1);

                    app_info[counter] = new AppInfo(pm.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo), 
                            String.valueOf(pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)));

                    System.out.println(counter);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                counter++;
            }

           adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, app_info);
            listApplication.setAdapter(adapter);




            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i=0;i<adapter.mCheckStates.size();i++)
                    {




                        if(adapter.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                        {

                                           result.append(app_info[i].applicationName);
                            result.append("\n");




                        }

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(SelectAppActivity.this,          result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

          }}
```

**MainActivity.java**
It contains the sliding drawer which shows all  installed apps but i want to display on the checked apps in this sliding drawer .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DrawerAdapter drawerAdapterObject;
AppInfoAdapter adapter;
GridView drawerGrid;
SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;
RelativeLayout homeView;
AppStringValues[] appString;
class Pac {
    Drawable icon;
    String name;
    String packageName;
    String label;
}

Pac[] pacs;
PackageManager pm;
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager;
LauncherAppWidgetHost mAppWidgetHost;
int REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET = 900;
int numWidgets;
ImageButton gotoAppSelector;
Button GetIt;
static boolean appLaunchable = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gotoAppSelector=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.appselector);
    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    mAppWidgetHost = new LauncherAppWidgetHost(this, R.id.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);

    drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    homeView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_view);
    GetIt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.getIt);
    pm = getPackageManager();

    set_pacs();
    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened() {
            appLaunchable = true;
        }
    });

    homeView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            selectWidget();
            return false;
        }
    });

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
    filter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(new PacReceiver(), filter);
}


public void set_pacs() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> pacsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    pacs = new Pac[pacsList.size()];
    for (int I = 0; I < pacsList.size(); I++) { 
            pacs[I] = new Pac();
            pacs[I].icon = pacsList.get(I).loadIcon(pm);
            pacs[I].packageName = pacsList.get(I).activityInfo.packageName;
            pacs[I].name = pacsList.get(I).activityInfo.name;
            pacs[I].label = pacsList.get(I).loadLabel(pm).toString();           
    }

    new SortApps().exchange_sort(pacs);
    drawerAdapterObject = new DrawerAdapter(this, pacs);
    drawerGrid.setAdapter(drawerAdapterObject);
    drawerGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListener(this, pacs,
            pm));
    drawerGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new DrawerLongClickListener(this,
            slidingDrawer, homeView, pacs));        
}

public class PacReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        set_pacs();
    }

  }
}
```